# Preserve dynamically added <title> in Angular while reloading page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a possibility when refreshing the page to save the  tag that has been dynamically added ?

Now, the moment I refresh the page, while loading, the title tag changes to the original one, which I set in the `index.html`. When the page is loaded, the title tag then comes back to the correct one which is dynamically added. But, I want the title tag to stay the same while the page is refreshing.

This is my app.component.ts:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.activatedRoute),
      map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
      }),
      filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
      mergeMap((route) => route.data)
    )
      .subscribe((event) => {
        console.log(event)
        this.translateService.get(event['title']).subscribe(name => {
          this._seoService.updateTitle(name);
        });
        this._seoService.updateDescription(event['description'])
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to make use of [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store your dynamic title in there. Here's a simple example where I am storing the title in Local storage and refreshing the page, and retaining my title back. Angular provides a service called [Title](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title) that allows us dynamically update the title anytime.

```html
<button (click)="setItem()">Click to set a title</button>

<p *ngIf="showInfo" >Refresh the page now :)</p>
```

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  showInfo = false;  

  constructor(private titleService: Title) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getItem();
  }

  setItem() {
    localStorage.setItem('title', 'Hey World!');
    this.showInfo = true;
    this.getItem();
  }

  getItem() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('title'))
      this.titleService.setTitle(localStorage.getItem('title'));
    else this.titleService.setTitle('No title');
  }
}
```

Here's a [live application](https://angular-ivy-zdtcuh.stackblitz.io).

Code - [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdtcuh?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. I was thinking about <title> tag inside `<head>` tag.

Comment: My bad. I completely misunderstood the title for heading element. I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thansks, now is better, but when I run your live application, set the title to "Hey World" and then refresh the page, for about 2 or 3 seconds for title is showing url "https://angular-ivy-zdtcuh.stackblitz.io/", and then again "Hey World". I want "Hey World" to be all the time while refreshing, if you unterstand me.

Comment: Not sure if it is because of that live server that I used for this example. But this works fine as expected in my local. Make sure you add `Title` in the providers array in app.module.ts

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? @StefanT